# Does the union operator ensure same rate of consumption from all datastreams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Does the Apache Flink's [union](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#union) operator ensure that the rate of consumption from the data streams is same?

If the data streams are kafka topics, can a scenario happen when only one of the topic is being read through and no messages are being read from the another?

If so how can I detect and prevent it?

Put other ways I want to make sure that the watermarks (event-time) of the two data-streams in the union, is the same or within a window and that watermark is only X hours behind the current epoch time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union operator will read from both input streams, but there's no strong guarantee as to the specific behavior. [Watermark alignment](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-alignment) is designed to help in cases like this. What it allows you to do is to avoid having one stream get too far ahead of the other by throttling the sources as needed to keep their watermarks roughly aligned.

Comment: Nice, looks like alignment will solve it. In the idle section, the doc says "the watermark will be held back, because it is computed as the minimum over all the different parallel watermarks` I'm a bit confused, if there are different parallel watermarks per kafka partition (splits?) then which watermark is being held back?

Comment: Reading how data sources work, the description says that a split is kafka topic. If a TM commits a offset, then how does JM know at which watermark a split is? I would imagine the JM would need to know about it for watermark alignment.

Comment: In the case of Kafka, each partition is a split. Watermarks are computed for each partition, then propagated as the minimum of all local watermarks.